# Config Yii::WebApplication without Constructor

Tags: php, oop, yii

In bootstrap of Yii  1.1 (app/index.php, Line 13), we boot up application with `Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();` command and `createWebApplication` method is (framework/YiiBase.php, Line 96)

```
public static function createWebApplication($config=null)
{
    return self::createApplication('CWebApplication',$config);
}
```

such that `createWebApplication` method is (framework/YiiBase, Line 123)

```
public static function createApplication($class,$config=null)
{
    return new $class($config);
}
```

So `createApplication('CWebApplication',$config)` interpret to a thing like `new CWebApplication($config);`, humm? But on `CWebApplication` class, we don't have any constructor! (framework/yiilite.php, Line 1622).

**Now question is:** How WebApplication get configurations on `$config` variable and adapts herself to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below function will return `return new CWebApplication($config);`

```
public static function createApplication($class,$config=null)
{
    return new $class($config);

}
```

If you check CWebApplication class extend CApplication,
CWebApplication.php

```
 class CWebApplication extends CApplication
    {
...
```

In CApplication you will find constructor method where it is initalized, `framework/base/CApplication.php`

```
abstract class CApplication extends CModule
{

 ....
  public function __construct($config=null)
    {
        Yii::setApplication($this);

        // set basePath at early as possible to avoid trouble
        if(is_string($config))
            $config=require($config);
        if(isset($config['basePath']))
        {
            $this->setBasePath($config['basePath']);
            unset($config['basePath']);
        }
        else
            $this->setBasePath('protected');
        Yii::setPathOfAlias('application',$this->getBasePath());
        Yii::setPathOfAlias('webroot',dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
        if(isset($config['extensionPath']))
        {
            $this->setExtensionPath($config['extensionPath']);
            unset($config['extensionPath']);
        }
        else
            Yii::setPathOfAlias('ext',$this->getBasePath().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'extensions');
        if(isset($config['aliases']))
        {
            $this->setAliases($config['aliases']);
            unset($config['aliases']);
        }

        $this->preinit();

        $this->initSystemHandlers();
        $this->registerCoreComponents();

        $this->configure($config);
        $this->attachBehaviors($this->behaviors);
        $this->preloadComponents();

        $this->init();
    }


abstract class CApplication
{
    protected $config=array();

    public function __construct($config=null) {

        echo "CApplication::construct() called";

        // DO anyting with config arrray which is from /protected/config/main.php
         //$this->config = $config;

    }

}
```

CWebApplication inherit CApplication so it also inherit Constructor method. 
To get the idea you can check my below example.

> Edit

```
    abstract class CApplication
{
    protected $config=array();

    public function __construct($config=null) {

        echo "CApplication::construct() called";

        // DO anyting with config arrray which is from /protected/config/main.php
         //$this->config = $config;

    }

}

class CWebApplication extends CApplication
{

    public function test(){

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($this->config);
        echo "</pre>";
    }

}

$config =  array(
    "name"          =>"My Web Application",
    "components"    => array(

        "db"        => "connectionstring:..",
        "urlManage"=> array(),
    )

);

$obj =  new CWebApplication($config);
```

Comment: But on `CWebApplication` we don't call parent's constructor. For calling `CApplication` constructor, we must have something like `parent::__constrcut` on code, right?

Comment: Thanks Yatin, Now i understand a new thing :-).